# Group the query into 3 columns, and display the sums for another column in Apex Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I want to make a report. In my request it is not difficult. I specify dates and also type of record (positive or subtractive) in this request. I want this query to be grouped by fields CONTRACTORID, ITEMID ORGANIZATION. And withdraw the amount on the NETTO.

```
select
  ID, DOCNUMBER,DOCDATE,PRINTNUMBER,DRIVERID,CONTRACTORID,ITEMID,
  BRUTTO,TARE,NETTO,
  DS_ID,
  DAT_A,
  MILEAGE,
  ORGANIZATION,
  sum(NETTO)
from WAYBILL
where trunc(DOCDATE) between to_date(:P115_D1,'dd.mm.yyyy')
                         and to_date(:P115_D2,'dd.mm.yyyy')
and DIRECTIONID = :P115_DIRECTIONID 
group by 
  ID, DOCNUMBER,DOCDATE,PRINTNUMBER,DRIVERID,CONTRACTORID,ITEMID,
  BRUTTO,TARE,NETTO,
  DS_ID,
  DAT_A,
  MILEAGE,
  ORGANIZATION
```

Comment: If you want to group by contractorid, itemid, and organization, why then do you select all those other columns? Just remove them from the select clause and group by clause and you are done, I'd say.

Comment: Provide your expected result

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I want to see other columns in the report as well, but to make the net amount only by grouped columns. It's possible?

Answer (score 0):

It *seems* you want to show the complete rows, each with the netto sum per its contractorid, itemid, and organization. You can achieve this with a window function:

```
select
  id,  docnumber, docdate, printnumber, driverid, contractorid, itemid, 
  brutto, tare, netto, ds_id, dat_a, mileage, organization,
  sum(netto) over (partition by contractorid, itemid, organization) as netto_sum
from waybill
where trunc(docdate) between to_date(:p115_d1,'dd.mm.yyyy')
                         and to_date(:p115_d2,'dd.mm.yyyy')
and directionid = :p115_directionid 
order by id;
```

Comment: Thanks . But maybe you don't fully understand me. So I want to show whole lines, but each of them does not have a total amount for each contractor. And just the value, the amount I want to display in this report (in the net column). For example, I have records that some organizations have documents. And I want to withdraw the amount for this organization in this report, if also converge two fields contractorid, itemid.

Comment: Maybe he didn't fully understand you because you did not provide the expected output.

Comment: Yes, maybe I don't fully understand. And it seems I am not the only one :-) So, follow Jim Macaulay's advice in the request comments and edit your request to show some sample data and the expected result.